# $f$ is a constant function or has a zero in $G$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G$ be a bounded region and suppose $f$ is continuous on $\overline G$ and analytic on $G$. Show that if there is a constant $c ≥ 0$ such that $| f(z)| = c$ for all $z$ on the boundary of $G$ then either $f$ is a constant
function or $f$ has a zero in $G$.

My try:

Suppose $f$ doesn't have a zero in $G$. Then $g=\frac{1}{f}$ is perfectly well defined, analytic on $G$ and continuous on $\partial G$. Now if $c=0$, then we have nothing to show . (By maximum-modulus Principle, $|f(z)| \le 0$ forall $z \in \overline G $ which in turn would say that f is a constant). Now suppose $c \ne 0$. Then Maximum modulus principle applied to both $f$ and $g$ would say that $|f(z)| \le c$ and $|g(z)| \le \frac{1}{c}$ for all $z \in \overline G$. This would give that $|f(z)|=c$ for all $z \in \overline G$. Since $f$ is analytic on $G$, f would be a constant.

Is this alright??

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Perhaps you would format $G^{-}$ as $\overline G$ produced by the $\TeX$-command `\overline G`.

Comment: @String.. is the solution okay??

Comment: The solution is correct. But you don't need to use the maximum-modulus principle to form the implication: $|f(z)| \leq 0$ on $\overline{G}$ implies $f$ is constant on $\overline{G}$. If the modulus is everywhere zero, the function is everywhere zero.